# ng-table reload does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, ngtable

I created a `ng-table` like:

```
data = $scope.publications;
        $scope.tablePublications = new ngTableParams({
       page: 1,            // show first page
       count: 20      // count per pages
    }, {
       total: data.length, // length of data
       getData: function($defer, params) {
           // use build-in angular filter
           var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                               $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                               data;

       $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
   }
});
```

When searching, a function is called that retrieves info from API and then calls the `reloadTable` function:

```
$scope.reloadTable = function(publications){
    $scope.tablePublications.data = publications;
    $scope.tablePublications.reload();
    $scope.tablePublications.reloadPages();
  }
```

Now `$scope.tablePublications.data` has a new information but `.reload()` doesn't work and doesn't refresh the table.

I change my code for that

```
$scope.search = function(page){
    if($scope.searchText!=="" || $scope.searchText !== "undefined")
    {
        $scope.isSearch=true;
        Minisite.searchPublications({search: $scope.searchText, page: page}, function(publications){
            $scope.total=publications.total;
            $scope.publications = publications.publications;
            $scope.tablePublications.data = {};
            $scope.tablePublications.reload();
        });
    }
}
```

Minisite is a factory that retrieve hash from API, and then i reloaded my tablePublications but doesn´t work. I have similar code in other functions and work fine and i dont understand it.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question - check the top answer - it's likely to be related to data.length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325994/ng-table-not-working-for-dynamic-data

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since you are probably outside of the digest cycle given that you are calling an api, you should try `$scope.$apply()` like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.reloadTable = function(publications){
        $scope.tablePublications.data = publications;
        $scope.tablePublications.reload();
        $scope.tablePublications.reloadPages();
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn´t work, $digest already error. I add a setTimeout for executing $apply but doesn´t work