# implementation of ng-table angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I want to implement ng-table for my project Spring and angular JS HTML5  but the problem when i add the ng-table nothing worked .

---App.JS----

```
    angular
  .module('TimeLeaveProject', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngTable'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'DemoCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

--Controller AngularJS ---

```
angular.module('TimeLeaveProject', ['ngTable'])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    alert("demoCTRL"); 

    $http.get('/users/all').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });

})
```

---HTML Page--

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" style="margin-top: 10%;text-align: center;" class="jumbotron">



    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table ng-table class="table">

   <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.password}}</td>
    </tr>



   </table>
```

**and i add the local link for ng-table in my index.html page . The problem that i got nothing , all the views doesn't work .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i declared the ng-table in app.js so I shouldn't declared in the controller

```
angular.module('TimeLeaveProject')
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    alert("demoCTRL"); 

    $http.get('/users/all').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have forgotten to inject $http in your controller:

```
angular.module('TimeLeaveProject', ['ngTable'])
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    alert("demoCTRL"); 

    $http.get('/users/all').
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });

})
```

Comment: have you checked if the http.get.success is returning what you expect?

Comment: yes i was working before with HTML 5 table and it's ok

Comment: Can you compare to what I've done here, to see what's different http://plnkr.co/edit/hH4B9z8Lqy1LSX4d6eBf?p=preview

Comment: the problem that in the javascript console they didn't show any error and also every other page didn't work so i think the problem is in app.js

Comment: as i checked the problem is in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Can you try declaring a default value for $scope.users, and then see if its coming up ? If yes , then the problem is that , your view is not getting updated when your http call returns data.

Comment: Are you sure , for reference , look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325994/ng-table-not-working-for-dynamic-data . Can you add the code in plunker ?

Comment: can you give the link to plunker ? its easier to debug there

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your `tableParams` ?

If yes, make sure they are declared **after you have received the data**, like this :

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 10 // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });

});
```

[**Example plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTjYaQ3DmEjO1GT6TVoC?p=preview)

Comment: you can check this exemple that i did it without tableParams and it worked  http://plnkr.co/edit/55nemp?p=streamer

Comment: @PasstissiPhone So... Is your problem fixed ? I'd recommend using the tableParams btw, that'll give you access to sorting, filtering, grouping, pagination...

Comment: i will use it thanks everyone the problem was fixed .

Answer (score 0):

Next time give a try to #ngTasty table pagination :)

http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/directive/table

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-grid instead of ng-table.

It provides lot of functionalities like paging, filtering and row selection.

> $scope.filterOptions = {      filterText : "",        useExternalFilter : true
>     };  $scope.totalServerItems = 0;    $scope.pagingOptions = {
>         pageSizes : [ 5, 10, 20 ],      pageSize : 10,      currentPage : 1     };
>     $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize) {         var
>   pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
>         $scope.myData = pagedData;      $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
>         if (!$scope.$$phase) {          $scope.$apply();        }   };
>     $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(pageSize, page, searchText) {
>         setTimeout(function() {             var data;           if (searchText) {
>                 var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
>                 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getData').success(
>                         function(largeLoad) {
>                             data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
>                                 return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase()
>                                         .indexOf(ft) != -1;
>                             });
>                             $scope.setPagingData(data, page, pageSize);
>                         });             } else {
>                 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getData').success(
>                         function(largeLoad) {
>                             $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad, page, pageSize);
>                         });             }       }, 100);    };
>
> $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,
>             $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);
>
> $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {       if
>   (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
>             $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,
>                     $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
>                     $scope.filterOptions.filterText);       }   }, true);   $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function(newVal, oldVal) {       if
>   (newVal !== oldVal) {
>             $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize,
>                     $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage,
>                     $scope.filterOptions.filterText);       }   }, true);
>
> $scope.gridOptions = {      data : 'myData',        enablePaging : true,
>         showFooter : true,      multiSelect : false,        totalServerItems :
>   'totalServerItems',       pagingOptions : $scope.pagingOptions,
>         filterOptions : $scope.filterOptions,       selectedItems : []  };