# ngTable, how to load new data after withstanding data has been seen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am using ngTable to show records to user, calling for data after every page would be pointless because I'll be just overusing the server when it isn't even necessary.

What I want to do is to add new data to the whole thing after the user has seen the old data completely. Let's say when the page is loaded I am loading 100 records and now `ngTable` will be able to show 100 data to the user. Now, when the user has seen 100 data I want to make a fresh request and update the table with new data elements.

I am clueless on how to make this work as something like this isn't mentioned anywhere in their official documentation or stackoverflow either.

Comment: Keep track of the scrollbar. When it's at the bottom, they've seen it all. After that, make the request and append the new data to your model variable.

Comment: handling the scrollbar specifically for 10th page, if I could handle the event particularly for that page I'd do it simply to solve the problem but I haven't seen any such option as of now

Comment: Are you using pagination (like ng-pagination where it hides/shows) or actual pages?

Comment: The ng-table comes with the pagination tabs so I am not adding them explicitly